# Count Outlook VBA attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

Can you help me to improve the below VBA code to be able to correctly count e-mails + attachments form a selected range (outlook 2010)

```
Sub CountAttachmentsMulti()

Set mySelect = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
For Each Item In mySelect
j = Item.Attachments.Count + j
i = i + 1
Next Item
MsgBox "Selected " & i & " messages with " & j & " attachements"

End Sub
```

That is the code the problem is that counts also as attachments the picture in the signatures and give a wrong count meaning more attachments then the actually are

Can you help to amend the code to bypass from counting the images in signatures

BR

Gabi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub CountAttachmentsValid()

Dim olkItem As Outlook.mailitem
Dim olkAttachment As Outlook.attachment

Dim strFilename As String
Dim strExtension As String
Dim lngExtIndex As Long
Dim strBaseFilename As String
Dim cnt As Long

Dim mySelect As Selection

Dim iExt As Long
Dim validExtString As String
Dim validExtArray() As String

validExtString = ".doc .docx .xls .xlsx .msg .pdf .txt" ' <---- Update as needed
validExtArray = Split(validExtString, " ")

Set mySelect = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each olkItem In mySelect

    For Each olkAttachment In olkItem.Attachments

        On Error GoTo cannotPerformOperation
        strFilename = olkAttachment.FileName
        lngExtIndex = InStrRev(strFilename, ".")
        strBaseFilename = Left(strFilename, lngExtIndex - 1)
        strExtension = Mid(strFilename, lngExtIndex)

        For iExt = 0 To UBound(validExtArray)

            If LCase(strExtension) = LCase(validExtArray(iExt)) Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                Exit For
            End If

        Next iExt

skipped:

    Next olkAttachment

Next olkItem

GoTo exiting

cannotPerformOperation:
'Debug.Print " ** " & olkAttachment.DisplayName & " not counted"
Resume skipped

exiting:
    MsgBox "Selected " & mySelect.count & " messages with " & cnt & " recognized attachments"

End Sub
```